# php - File Uploading Error

Tags: php, angularjs

Im trying to add file uploading to my app but for some reason the php script doesnt move the file. I'm using angularjs and the code works fine but in the script it doesn't move/upload the file as it's supposed. Below is the code I have

```
<?php
    $name = $_FILES['filee']['name'];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['filee']['tmp_name'];
    $loc = '/media/img/';

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filee']['name'], $loc)){
        echo $_FILES['filee']['tmp_name'].$loc.$name;
    }
?>
```

I don't see whats wrong with the script!!

Answer (score 1):

you need to use tmp_name in the first argument of move_uploaded_file() function  as below

```
<?php
    $name = $_FILES['filee']['name'];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['filee']['tmp_name'];
    $loc = 'media/img/'.$name; //desitination needs file name also
    if(!is_dir('media/img/') && !file_exists('media/img') ) {
      mkdir('media/img',0777,true);
    }
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filee']['tmp_name'], $loc)){
        echo $_FILES['filee']['tmp_name'].$loc.$name;
    }
?>
```

also make sure form has enctype attribute

Comment: I used to tmp_name value but it still didnt work, i changed it to name to test.

Comment: add name at the end of $loc as i have set because destination should have file name in it and check form has enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute

Comment: That didnt seem to work for me, could there be something else?

Comment: it you are using linux, there should be directory write permission, so use chmod to change upload directory permission to 777

Comment: I'm using an online/cloud based IDE maybe thats the problem? as far as uploading files? Its called koding.com

Comment: ide hasn't do anything with your upload directory, i suggest you to check the upload directory path is correct or not for ex. $loc exists

Comment: i have tweaked code and added directory creation if its not exists try this code

Comment: When you say media/img and so on, does it imply to your website slash a child directory? like facebook.com/media/img ?

Comment: no, it depends on the configuration here the path is physical path not the url when i start the path without slash means the relative path from the execution point